# Checkbox using HTML and CSS Only for outlook web (Not the desktop App)

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, email-templates

In outlook windows desktop app, checkbox isnt supported as it uses MS word as its rendering engine. However, in the web app, checkbox works and [Can I email site](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=checked) says clearly that checkbox:checked is supported on outlook.com i.e. outlook web.

I want to hide data by default, and when checkbox is ":checked" , I want to show the data.**However, in the mail, i am able to click on the checkbox but not able to display the hidden data. Is there any other way to show and hide data in outlook web ?**

here is the fiddle that I wrote : https://jsfiddle.net/cL2dbpq5/

here is how it looks in outlook web:

[image: Image doesnt display hidden data]

code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
    <style>
     
        #content {
            display: none;
        }

        #show:checked~#content {
            display: block;
        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <input id="show" type=checkbox>
    <label for="show">Click Me</label>
    <span id="content">Text visible when checkbox is clicked</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you show the code of the email?

Comment: The code of the email sender is in java and its based on this : https://javabydeveloper.com/spring-boot-email-template/

Comment: Usually emails are made by using HTML and inline CSS. From what you wrote I assume that you have no control over the CSS as the email is generated automatically, is that the case?

Comment: I have already tried using inline CSS. Above code works fine in iOS apps. So there is no problem with the java code.

Comment: There is no problem with the code you showed. I don't remember if I have seen a dynamic email with the functionality you described. Emails are static. Can't you do this: send a sample email to yourself and get its code. Let's see what it contains.

Comment: You can't have interactivity in an email. This would be too big of a security risk. Send a link to a webpage where you can have this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [on Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-pseudo-class-checked/#checked-cite-note-1), `:checked` is “*Only supported on type selectors.*” on Outlook.com. This means you can use `input:checked` but not `#show:checked`. So in your case replace your style with the following and it should work.

```
input:checked~#content {
    display: block;
}
```