# Use CSS Checkbox to show and hide data in outlook Web (Not outlook desktop App)

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, email-templates

Unlike outlook desktop app which uses MS Word as its renderring engine, outlook web using webkit supports CSS to great extent. **Below is HTML CSS email template for outlook web (Not the outlook desktop App),**

I am using the CSS only "checkbox" hack, where clicking on a checkbox will hide and show data. Something like this, https://jsfiddle.net/a4qn2tuc/. Code of this fiddle works fine in outlook web app.

Using the checkbox hack, I am trying to show and hide data of a table row. Clciking on **"click Me"** shows the hidden row, here is the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/L5th9vdb/

**The problem is that in outlook web, I am able to click on "checkbox" to show and hide data, but I am not able to click on "Click Me" button of the row to show and hide data.** "Click Me" text is the label field, below is the snippet from the fiddle. Wrapping the checkbox within label tag isnt possible for my table design. Any idea on where I am making the mistake **to make the label clickable**? Wrapping the checkbox within label tag isnt possible for my table design.

Please note that the label "click Me" is clcikable for iOS, android, mac OS - the problem is only in outlook web.

**Thanks for all the help.**

Code :

```html
<td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align:center;">
    <label class="tab-label" for="row2">Click Me</label>
</td>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkbox using HTML and CSS Only for outlook web (Not the desktop App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772294/checkbox-using-html-and-css-only-for-outlook-web-not-the-desktop-app)

Comment: Thanks for responding. It doesnt answer the question. Both are different issues.