# checkbox to hide and show data without using for/id attributes using CSS only

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, email-templates

I have a table. Clicking on "click me" shows the hidden data. Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L5th9vdb/

The code is part of an email template where for/id to link between checkbox and label isnt supported. I tried to wrap the checkbox in the label but it messes up the table. Is there any way to keep the table design intact and have the checkbox show/hide the row without using id/for attributes ?

code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

</html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table</title>
    <!-- add icon link -->
    <link rel="icon" href="./MAblueIcon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<head>

    <style>
        @charset "UTF-8";

        /* #row1,#row2 {
            display: none;
        }  */

        .tab-label {
            /* display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 1em; */
            background: #b9ce44;
            font-weight: bold;
            /* cursor: pointer; */
            /* Icon */
        }

        /* .tab-label:hover {
            background: #1a252f;
        } */

        /* .tab-label::after {
            content: "❯";
            width: 1em;
            height: 1em;
            text-align: center;
            transition: all 0.35s;
        } */

        .tab-content {
            overflow: hidden;
            max-height: 0;
            padding: 0 1em;
            color: #2c3e50;
            background: white;
            transition: all 0.35s;
        }

        /* input:checked ~ .tab-label {
            background: #1a252f;
        } */

        /* input:checked ~ .tab-label::after {
            transform: rotate(90deg);

        } */



        input:checked ~ .tab-content {
            max-height: 100vh;
            padding: 1em;
        }
    </style>


</head>



<body style="margin: 0;padding: 0;min-width: 100%;width: 100%;
max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; height: 100%;max-height: 100%;  background: rgb(231, 207, 192);
min-height: 100vh;">

    <div id="page-wrap" style="margin: 50px;background: cornflowerblue;">

        <h1 style="margin: 0;line-height: 3;text-align: center;font: 30px/1.4 Georgia, Serif;">Table</h1>

        <table role="presentation" style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2" colspan="1"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>


                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <!-- Ist Row -->
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">

                        <label class="tab-label" for="row1">Click Me</label>


                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Ist accordion -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="11" style="border: solid 1px white;text-align: center;padding: 0;">
                        <input id="row1" type="checkbox">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <table role="presentation"
                                style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 10px auto;background-color: aqua;">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2" colspan="1"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <!-- <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th> -->
                                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>


                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <!-- <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th> -->
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>


                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">Athens</td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">Edlund, Ben
                                        (July 1996).</td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td> -->
                                </tr>


                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>




                <!-- 2nd Row -->
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">

                        <label class="tab-label" for="row2">Click Me</label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 2nd accordion -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="11" style="border: solid 1px white;text-align: center;padding: 0;">
                        <input id="row2" type="checkbox">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <table role="presentation"
                                style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 10px auto;background-color: aqua;">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2" colspan="1"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <!-- <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th> -->
                                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>


                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>


                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>

                                </tr>


                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>




            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkbox using HTML and CSS Only for outlook web (Not the desktop App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772294/checkbox-using-html-and-css-only-for-outlook-web-not-the-desktop-app)

Comment: @Nathan, my current question is totally different. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I believe you use the name attribute, as per https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-interactive-forms-in-email/

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to hide the inputs?
I used this css

`input{ display: none; }`

I do know the original design, I hope this can help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

</html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table</title>
    <!-- add icon link -->
    <link rel="icon" href="./MAblueIcon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<head>

    <style>
        @charset "UTF-8";

        /* #row1,#row2 {
            display: none;
        }  */

        .tab-label {
            /* display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 1em; */
            background: #b9ce44;
            font-weight: bold;
            /* cursor: pointer; */
            /* Icon */
        }

        /* .tab-label:hover {
            background: #1a252f;
        } */

        /* .tab-label::after {
            content: "❯";
            width: 1em;
            height: 1em;
            text-align: center;
            transition: all 0.35s;
        } */

        .tab-content {
            overflow: hidden;
            max-height: 0;
            padding: 0 1em;
            color: #2c3e50;
            background: white;
            transition: all 0.35s;
        }

        /* input:checked ~ .tab-label {
            background: #1a252f;
        } */

        /* input:checked ~ .tab-label::after {
            transform: rotate(90deg);

        } */



        input:checked ~ .tab-content {
            max-height: 100vh;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        input{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>


</head>



<body style="margin: 0;padding: 0;min-width: 100%;width: 100%;
max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; height: 100%;max-height: 100%;  background: rgb(231, 207, 192);
min-height: 100vh;">

    <div id="page-wrap" style="margin: 50px;background: cornflowerblue;">

        <h1 style="margin: 0;line-height: 3;text-align: center;font: 30px/1.4 Georgia, Serif;">Table</h1>

        <table role="presentation" style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2" colspan="1"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>


                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"
                        style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                        Header</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <!-- Ist Row -->
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">

                        <label class="tab-label" for="row1">Click Me</label>


                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Ist accordion -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="11" style="border: solid 1px white;text-align: center;padding: 0;">
                        <input id="row1" type="checkbox">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <table role="presentation"
                                style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 10px auto;background-color: aqua;">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2" colspan="1"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <!-- <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th> -->
                                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>


                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <!-- <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th> -->
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>


                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">Athens</td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">Edlund, Ben
                                        (July 1996).</td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td> -->
                                </tr>


                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>




                <!-- 2nd Row -->
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">

                        <label class="tab-label" for="row2">Click Me</label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 2nd accordion -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="11" style="border: solid 1px white;text-align: center;padding: 0;">
                        <input id="row2" type="checkbox">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <table role="presentation"
                                style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 10px auto;background-color: aqua;">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2" colspan="1"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <!-- <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th> -->
                                        <th rowspan="1" colspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>


                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2"
                                            style="background: #333;color: white;font-weight: bold;padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">
                                            Header</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>


                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 6px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;">N/A
                                    </td>

                                </tr>


                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>




            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I guess you have misunderstood the problem. Thanks for responding anyways.